# How to find the columns that are part of a foreign key in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I have two tables `Parent` and `Child`.
I want to find all tuples from `Child` that have a foreign key dependency to a given tuple from `Parent`.

```
DataTable schema = Connection.GetSchema("ForeignKeys", new string[] { null, null, "Child", null });
```

I used the code above to retrieve data about the foreign keys inside `Child` but, as seen in the picture below, the resulting `DataTable` doesn't contain information about which columns are part of which foreign key.
[image: Columns of the resulting DataTable]

I was wondering if it's possible given just the table names and a `SqlConnection` to find all tuples inside `Child` that have a foreign key dependency to a given tuple in `Parent`.

Comment: It's crazy, isn't it?  The most important piece of information left out...